# CSS right border not fitting right

Tags: html, css, web

I'm just learning CSS and HTML and decided to have a go at making a mock up website. I'm having trouble with the border not meeting the end of the top bar. Other times I've had it go over.

https://jsfiddle.net/9gonuvu7/

```
#topnav li {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 16px 10px 10px 20px;
list-style: none;
color: white;
font-size: 1.2em;
border-right: solid #3E6F87 1px;
```

You can see this in the above link. If you could explain to me why this is happening and how I can avoid it in future I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the parent.

That's preventing it from reaching top.

```
#topbar {
background-color: #2A4F6E;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
padding: 0px 0 0px 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Now it reaches the top but still not the bottom?

Comment: change the `#topnav li`  and give it `padding: 16px 10px 12px 20px;`

Comment: and change the `#topbar h1` to `padding: 7px 50px 6px 40px;`

Comment: Could you possibly explain what's happening here?

Comment: sure, the problem is the height of the elements that have the border ( the `li & h1`), since the parent had 3px padding top and bottom the children only start 3px from top of the parent. That was preventing the border to go to the top. Same as bottom. What I recommend here is using line-height to line them vertically instead of padding. Giving the `li & h1` the ` line-height: 50px ` and removing all padding tops and bottom from the parent and children will vertically align them and ensure they have 50 height. Matching the size of the header. (Sorry if my english isn't clear enough)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, because you said you just started with HTML and CSS I changed a bit more in your code.

1. At the moment your fixedwith div has no impact on the code (maybe you use it in your full website).
2. You applied the background on the whole topbar, that HTML-wise also contains your menu points, assuming you only want your headline to have that blue background I swapped that property to the h1-tag.
   With this change the borderlines are overlapped b the headline, which should do the job.

[new JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9gonuvu7/13/)

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#topbar {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#topbar h1 {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #2A4F6E;
    padding: 7px 50px 7px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border-right: solid #3E6F87 1px;

}

#topnav {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
#topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px 10px 10px 20px;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-right: solid #3E6F87 1px;
}
#topnav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#topnav a:hover{
    color: #A97437;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="fixedwidth">
                <h1>Neil's Tech Reviews</h1>
                <div id="topnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Reviews</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```